# combine string with each and every string in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have cell array with full of string like below

```
a = 

    'one'      'two' 
    'three'    'four'
```

now I am assign the above cell array **a** to another cell array **b** first , second and third place Like below

```
b{1} =a;
 b{2} =a;
 b{3} =a;
```

now i want to combine the string `X = '-h';` with each and every string of  **b** cell array

How can I do ?

Example output is

```
b =        
        {2x2 cell}
        {2x2 cell}
        {2x2 cell};

b{1} ={'one-h' 'two-h' ;'three-h'  'four-h'};
b{2} ={'one-h' 'two-h' ;'three-h'  'four-h'};
b{3} ={'one-h' 'two-h' ;'three-h'  'four-h'};
```

but I need this output after assign the a value to b like step 2 (`b{1} = a`...) and string **X** must combine with **b** cell array only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
%// Using nested cellfun
b = cellfun(@(x) cellfun(@(y) strcat(y,'-h'),x,'Uni',0),b,'Uni',0);
```

**Output:**

```
>> b{1}

ans = 

'one-h'      'two-h' 
'three-h'    'four-h'
```